# yii generatepasswordhash not working

Tags: passwords, yii2, password-encryption

For some strange reasons, i am finding it difficult to login with yii->$app->generatePasswordhash($password.) I have a backedn where i register users and also change password. Users can login successfully when i created them but when i edit user password, the system keeps telling me invalid username or password. Below is my code.

```
//Model
Class Adminuser  extends ActiveRecord
{
 public $resetpassword
 public function activateuser($id,$newpassword)
    {
        //echo Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($newpassword); exit;
       $user = Adminuser::find()->where(['id' =>$id])->one();
       $user->status = self::SET_STATUS; 
       $user->password_reset_token = null;
       $user->password = Admin::genPassword($this->resetpassword); // this returns yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password)
        return $user->save();

    }
}
```

//controller action

```
 public function actionActivate($id)
    {

                $model = new Adminuser();
                $model->scenario = 'adminactivate';
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate())           {

            if($model->activateuser($id,$model->password))
            {
                //send a mail
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'New user has been activated.');
                return $this->redirect(['index']);
            }
            else
                $errors = $model->errors;
            }
            return $this->render('activate', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);

    }
```

Please i need help

Answer (score 0):

Your `activateuser()` method has `$newpassword` as an incoming parameter. Anyway you are using `$this->resetpassword` in `Admin::genPassword()`. Looks like that is the reason of the problem and all your passwords are generated based on `null` value. So try to use `$user->password = Admin::genPassword($newpassword);` instead.

Comment: Thank you. Would try it now and revert back